# qiskit save circuit with free parameters

Tags: qiskit, programming

Is there a way to save an instance of qiskit's `QuantumCircuit` in some format when the circuit has still some free parameters to be evaluated? I have tried using the qasm format but it seems it does not tolerate non-evaluated parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is - [QPY serialization](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/qpy.html). It is useful for the case you have depicted but also for many other cases where the QASM format imposes restrictions.

**An example:**

Creating the circuit and dumping it to a `qpy` file:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, qpy
from qiskit.circuit import Parameter

theta = Parameter("$\Theta$")
qc = QuantumCircuit(1)
qc.ry(theta, 0)

with open("qc.qpy", "wb") as qpy_file_write:
    qpy.dump(qc, qpy_file_write)
```

Loading the circuit and assigning a value to $\theta$:

```
import numpy as np
from qiskit import qpy

with open("qc.qpy", "rb") as qpy_file_read:
    qc_loaded = qpy.load(qpy_file_read)[0]

qc_loaded = qc_loaded.bind_parameters([np.pi/2])
qc_loaded.draw("mpl")
```

Displays:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It could be great if you could also spend a couple of works on how to then recover the parameter and bound it to some value, is that possible?

Comment: I have edited my answer above with an example. If you need to define several parameters it  can be done using `ParameterVector` - https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.ParameterVector.html. Let me know if you need anything more.